# Why does water run into my toilet bowl when I turn on another faucet?

Tags: toilet

The toilet flushes fine, but when we turn the bathroom tap or shower on, water starts to run into the bowl again.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Is it the water from the toilet tank running into the bowl(doubt) or water flowing out of the bowl into drain pipe.  Sounds like a vent problem(blockage).

Comment: Sometimes if debris are partially blocking the fill valve a pressure change can cause it to flow again.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the fill valve will most likely work.  Most modern fill valves use a diaphragm system similar to a sprinkler valve. These work by changing the pressure on top and bottom of the diaphragm. As the water rises the float connected to the little arm closes a small bleed hole. the pressure on top of the valve rises and closes the diaphragm.  These valves are very sensitive to pressure variations. Like when you turn on a shower or such. When new they should be fine. but as the rubber ages they get less flexible, and the little stopper plug may not seal as well. So a new one will likely solve your problem. As an alternative you can still get the old style "ball and cock" valve. The one with the big float ball on the end of an arm.These don't use the diaphragm type valve, and so don't care about pressure variations. On the con side. They don't fill quite as fast and might be noisier.